# Woocommerce - How to get product data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to get the product data for a plug in I am modifying but the `$product` variable always seems to be null. in other functions it returns an array of product data. I have tried many solutions but cannot figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wmc_get_price' ) ) {
    function wmc_get_price( $price, $currency_code = false, $is_shipping = false ) {
 
        if ( is_admin() && ! is_ajax() ) {
            return $price;
        }
        $setting             = WOOMULTI_CURRENCY_Data::get_ins();
        $allow_multi_pay     = $setting->get_enable_multi_payment();
        $equivalent_currency = $setting->get_param( 'equivalent_currency' );

        if ( isset( $price ) ) {
            $price = (float) str_replace( ',', '.', $price );
        }
        echo $product;
        if ( ! $allow_multi_pay && is_checkout() && ! $equivalent_currency ) {
            return $price;
        }

        /*Check currency*/
        $selected_currencies = $setting->get_list_currencies();
        $current_currency    = $setting->get_current_currency();

        if ( ! $current_currency ) {
            return $price;
        }
        if ( $price ) {
            // IF product === nameyourprice {$price = $price;}
            if ( ywcnp_product_is_name_your_price( $product ) ) {
                $price = $price;
                $price = $is_shipping ? $price : apply_filters( 'wmc_get_price', $price, $currency_code );
            }
            elseif ( $currency_code && isset( $selected_currencies[ $currency_code ] ) ) {
                $price = $price * (float) $selected_currencies[ $currency_code ]['rate'];
                $price = $is_shipping ? $price : apply_filters( 'wmc_get_price', $price, $currency_code );
//              $price = apply_filters( 'wmc_get_price', $price, $currency_code );
            } else {
                $price = $price * (float) $selected_currencies[ $current_currency ]['rate'];
                $price = $is_shipping ? $price : apply_filters( 'wmc_get_price', $price, $current_currency );
//              $price = apply_filters( 'wmc_get_price', $price, $current_currency );
            }
        }

        return (float) $price; //(float)
    }
}
```

Comment: The function does not take this as a parameter, so where is it supposed to magically come from?

Comment: Whenever I add it as a parameter it throws an error

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
I fixed it by wrapping the function in `add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'wc_init' ); function wc_init(){}`

This allowed me to retrieve the `wc_get_price()` function and the `$product` variable.

Just figuring out Wordpress include system.